# Calling a block by AJAX

Tags: 7, ajax

I want to call a block on a page by AJAX. This is appearing in content and not in a block region.

[Use case: I have a View listing countries and their details; I want to add, at the top of the View, the user's country. I want the page to be cached, hence using AJAX to call back a View Block]

In the header of my view I have:

```
<div id="load-ajax"></div>
<script>
(function ($) {
  $('#load-ajax').load('/example/test');
}) (jQuery);
</script>
```

In hook_menu I have

```
$items['example/test'] = array(
    'title' => 'AJAX Delivery Test', 
    'page callback' => 'show_example_block', 
    'delivery callback' => '_basic_print', 
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

I then have two functions:

```
function _basic_print($page_callback_result){
  print $page_callback_result;
}

function show_example_block(){
  if (isset($_COOKIE['country'])){
    return views_embed_view('example', 'example_block', $_COOKIE['country']);
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering whether I'm missing anything. Is there a simpler, slightly more native way of doing this?

Comment: This is a pretty nice way of doing it if you ask me.  For those wondering, `_basic_print` is essentially a way of returning an AJAX request via `hook_menu` without all the standard Drupal templating of a page as specified in `drupal_deliver_html_page`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block', 'view', 0);
print $block['content'];
?>
```

Try including the view block.