# Ajaxify certian content on the front page

Tags: ajax

My site uses dashboard as front page and loads boxes to show content. As there are many boxes, the page takes some time to load. So what i want to do now is to load the theme and interface first and then load the boxes using ajax.
Is there any kind of solution already available or something that needs to  be tailored.

My site is [here](http://www.monitorkashmir.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Ajax Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxblocks), which allows you to load a block on a given page via AJAX, after the page has loaded.

See also: [Calling a block by AJAX](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26525/calling-a-block-by-ajax)

Comment: thanku for the response..
yes i tried it, but i am using boxes for the views.. so i need a solution for the boxes module and not the blocks....

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. I haven't ever used Boxes, so I'm not sure if there's an easy way to integrate AJAX rendering of content with Boxes.